# MonetDB Slow Query with Index

Tags: indexing, monetdb

I created a table with 10GB (60M records), added unique index (hidden_id) manually after data insertion.
I had the simplest query but it took one minutes to complete.

```
select hidden_id from netflow where hidden_id = 350000;
```

And also the query took tens of minutes "`select * from netflow order by hidden_id limit 12500 offset 212500;`".
It really confuses me.

I post the analysis of the first query below. Any clue why it's so slow?

```
trace select hidden_id from netflow where hidden_id = 350000;

+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ticks    | stmt                                                             |
+==========+==================================================================+
|        3 | X_3 := sql.mvc();                                                |
|       15 | X_7=<tmp_2510>[69396995] := sql.bind(X_3=0,"sys","netflow","hidd |
:          : en_id",0);                                                       :
|      227 | X_4:bat[:oid,:oid] =<tmp_13332>[69396995] := sql.tid(X_3=0,"sys" |
:          : ,"netflow");                                                     :
| 72978741 | X_36=<tmp_4053>[1] := algebra.subselect(X_7=<tmp_2510>[69396995] |
:          : ,X_4=<tmp_13332>:bat[:oid,:oid][69396995],A0=350000:lng,A0=35000 :
:          : 0:lng,true,true,false);                                          :
|       17 | (X_10=<tmp_2175>[0],r1_10=<tmp_3416>[0]) := sql.bind(X_3=0,"sys" |
:          : ,"netflow","hidden_id",2);                                       :
|       14 | X_37=<tmp_13337>[0] := algebra.subselect(r1_10=<tmp_3416>[0],A0= |
:          : 350000:lng,A0=350000:lng,true,true,false);                       :
|        6 | X_13=<tmp_3416>[0] := sql.bind(X_3=0,"sys","netflow","hidden_id" |
:          : ,1);                                                             :
|       15 | X_38=<tmp_11053>[0] := algebra.subselect(X_13=<tmp_3416>[0],X_4= |
:          : <tmp_13332>:bat[:oid,:oid][69396995],A0=350000:lng,A0=350000:lng :
:          : ,true,true,false);                                               :
|        4 | X_15=<tmp_4053>[1] := sql.subdelta(X_36=<tmp_4053>[1],X_4=<tmp_1 |
:          : 3332>:bat[:oid,:oid][69396995],X_10=<tmp_2175>[0],X_37=<tmp_1333 :
:          : 7>[0],X_38=<tmp_11053>[0]);                                      :
|       20 | X_17=<tmp_11053>[1] := sql.projectdelta(X_15=<tmp_4053>[1],X_7=< |
:          : tmp_2510>[69396995],X_10=<tmp_2175>[0],r1_10=<tmp_3416>[0],X_13= :
:          : <tmp_3416>[0]);                                                  :
|        6 | X_18 := sql.resultSet(1,1,X_17=<tmp_11053>[1]);                  |
|        7 | sql.rsColumn(X_18=1,"sys.netflow","hidden_id","bigint",64,0,X_17 |
:          : =<tmp_11053>[1]);                                                :
|        2 | X_23 := io.stdout();                                             |
|       25 | sql.exportResult(X_23=="104d2":streams,X_18=1);                  |
|        1 | end s1_3;                                                        |
| 73011629 | X_5:void  := user.s1_3(350000:lng);                              |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is the table being created.

```
CREATE TABLE "netflow" (
    "time_seconds" double DEFAULT NULL,
    "parsed_date" timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
    "date_time_str" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    "ip_layer_protocol" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    "ip_layer_protocol_code" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    "first_seen_src_ip" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    "first_seen_dest_ip" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    "first_seen_src_port" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    "first_seen_dest_port" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    "more_fragments" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    "cont_fragments" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    "duration_seconds" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    "first_seen_src_payload_bytes" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    "first_seen_dest_payload_bytes" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    "first_seen_src_total_bytes" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    "first_seen_dest_total_bytes" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    "first_seen_src_packet_count" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    "first_seen_dest_packet_count" bigint DEFAULT NULL,
    "record_force_out" varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

**Update:**

the platform: Windows 7 without parallel

MonetDB version: MonetDB 5 server v11.15.19 "Feb2013-SP6"

description of the table in storage:

```
select * from storage() where "table"='netflow';
+--------+---------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+-----
-----+-----------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
| schema | table   | column                        | type      | location | count    | typewidth | columnsize | heapsize   | indices | sorted |
+========+=========+===============================+===========+==========+==========+===========+============+============+=========+========+
| sys    | netflow | time_seconds                  | double    | 17\1711  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | parsed_date                   | timestamp | 20\2054  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | date_time_str                 | varchar   | 07\734   | 69396995 |        21 |  277587980 | 2684354560 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | ip_layer_protocol             | bigint    | 62\6261  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | ip_layer_protocol_code        | varchar   | 62\6213  | 69396995 |         3 |   69396995 |     524288 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | first_seen_src_ip             | varchar   | 63\6342  | 69396995 |        11 |  138793990 |     524288 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | first_seen_dest_ip            | varchar   | 23\2324  | 69396995 |         8 |  138793990 |     524288 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | first_seen_src_port           | bigint    | 15\1574  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | first_seen_dest_port          | bigint    | 23\2370  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | more_fragments                | varchar   | 65\6521  | 69396995 |         1 |   69396995 |     524288 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | cont_fragments                | varchar   | 65\6524  | 69396995 |         1 |   69396995 |     524288 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | duration_seconds              | bigint    | 65\6560  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | first_seen_src_payload_bytes  | bigint    | 65\6561  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | first_seen_dest_payload_bytes | bigint    | 65\6562  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | first_seen_src_total_bytes    | bigint    | 65\6563  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | first_seen_dest_total_bytes   | bigint    | 65\6564  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | first_seen_src_packet_count   | bigint    | 65\6565  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | first_seen_dest_packet_count  | bigint    | 65\6566  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | record_force_out              | varchar   | 65\6567  | 69396995 |         1 |   69396995 |     524288 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | hidden_id                     | bigint    | 25\2510  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | false  |
| sys    | netflow | index_id                      | oid       | 73\7375  | 69396995 |         8 |  555175960 |          0 |       0 | true   |
+--------+---------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: How did you add the hidden_id column? Also: what release of Monet did you use? Did you compile it yourself?

Comment: And one other thing: could you run this command: select * from storage() where "table" = 'netflow'; and post the result?

Comment: "alter table ips_sample add hidden_id bigint not null auto_increment; ". After that I update the table to set it as unique index. I didn't compile MonetDB myself, I was using the Windows installer version.

Answer (score 2):

Beware, the SQL statement CREATE INDEX is silently ignored in MonetDB.
It will create the necessary hash indices upon need.
Your first query triggers this.

I also notice that you don't seem to run in parallel.
Please, always indicate the platform used and MonetDB Version.

Comment: How Do I know that I am running monetDB queries in parallel or not ?